# Split string from file txt

Tags: c, file, scanf

The C program must split the string when it finds ! or ? or .
The string must contain the \n newline and ! or ? or . where it is present. An example of the file test.txt

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
>   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud
>   exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit
>   laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur Quis autem vel eum 
>   iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae
>   consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

my code reads up to the first token, where am I wrong?

```
int main(){
    FILE *file;
    char stringa[MAXCHAR];

    file = fopen ("prova.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        perror("errore nell'apertura del file");
        return (1);
    }
    while (fscanf(file, "%[^!?.]", stringa) != EOF) {
        printf("Data from file:\n%s", stringa);
        //break; 
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

my output:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

Thanks for your help...

Comment: break statements was inserted accidentally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code reads up to the first token found but it puts back the tokens so even without the "break" your program will not read any further , it will go into an infinite loop because your while condition isn't so well defined , it should be :

```
 while (fscanf(file, "%[^!?.]", stringa) == 1) //checks if text was read successfully
```

Also you need to get rid of any tokens when encountered , this should do it:

```
while (fscanf(file, "%[^!?.]", stringa) == 1) {
        printf("Data from file: %s\n", stringa);
        fscanf(file,"%*[!?.]");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It exits because you used `break` as soon as you spot the `.`, `?` or `!` in input.
I believe what you want is to replace any of these three characters in input stream by `\n`.
If that's the case then replace `break` by `printf("\n")`

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to suggest replacing `break;` with `printf("\n");` as it doesn't really suggest that is needed, but removal of `break;` is spot on to avoid premature termination of the loop.